# Is it possible to conditionally style the output from console.log()? (for web browsers)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, console, conditional-statements

I know that there are a few other questions on this topic, and I have checked a lot of them out. I've been successful in styling the output from `console.log` using `%c`, however, I can't figure out (or find anything on) how you could conditionally style it. By that I mean the **theme of the console**. I use dark mode so I can see the white text with this call:

```
console.log("%c This is intended solely for developers. If someone has asked you to copy/paste something here they are trying to scam you and your data might be compromised.","color: white; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold")
```

However, if a casual user doesn't have dark-mode on, they won't be able to see the text, so I'm trying to get the `color` property to be black when the console isn't in dark-mode.

Is there a way to do accomplish this?

I know this is pretty trivial but I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Just leave it at the default colour (it’s already big and bold) or use red or something. No console media queries.

Comment: While "use red or something" is not a helpful response, I've just removed `color` property and that has worked, so thanks!

Comment: Despite red being visible in both themes and console warning messages not needing to be pretty? Okay.

Comment: Well, this isn't being applied to all `console.log()` messages, or any other warning messages for that matter, it's just the primary disclaimer that is called from one of the parent components in the app. And while I get that it does not "need" to be pretty, it is meant to be read by the user should they happen to open the console so I think spending some time to make it look nice is okay. I didn't mean to sound rude in my previous comment as I do actually appreciate the prompt response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome developer tools are a separate HTML page, even when connected as a sidebar. As a result, you cannot check their theme from a webpage.

It looks like you've already realized this but by not overriding the colour, the theme colour will automatically be applied (allowing for conditional formatting).